Загрузка изображений в SQLite
У меня есть таблица SQL, в которую пользователь загружает данный, среди столбцов есть столбец типа BLOB, где потенциально должны храниться изображения (таблица - база данных прочитанных пользователем книг, изображения - обложки).
У меня получилось реализовать загрузку изображения, преобразуя его в бинарный код, но проблема в том, что даже изображение меньше 100 Кб загружается в таком формате очень долго.
Может, есть какие-то другие пути хранения? Может, я чего-то упускаю?
Сомнения еще вызвал вот какой момент, я понимаю, что в аббревиатуре BLOB уже присутствует слово "бинарный", но вот на скриншоте ниже видно, что, если перетащить картинку в нужное поле, формат поля меняется на "Изображение". Нет ли возможности загружать картинки в таблицу без перевода в бинарные данные?

Как вообще оптимально хранить пользовательские изображения, связанные с базой данных?
    var img = texture.get_image()
    var ibytes = img.get_data()
    var bytes = ""
    for i in range (ibytes.size()):
        if(i ==0):
            bytes = str(ibytes[i])
        else:
            bytes = bytes + ',' + str(ibytes[i])
        
    dict["CoverImg"] = bytes

    db.insert_row(tableName,dict)


Я о Питон. У меня есть аналогичная база данных стихов с иллюстрациями. Загрузка всей записи стиха - текста, атрибутов стиха, изображения - выполняется мгновенно. Мало того, по ходу вынутое из базы изображение преобразуется в миниатюру, которая потом помещается в канвас во вновь создаваемой форме. База типа sqlite3, локальная. Ваша формулировка "таблица SQL", мягко говоря, ни о чём, а  строго - грубейшая ошибка. Уточните что за база и как именно она эксплуатируется, если хотите получить от вопроса пользу.

«какие-то другие пути хранения» — очевидно, в файлах без всяких там баз и таблиц. Тем не менее, загрузка блобов в базу всё равно не должна приводить к каким-то страшным тормозам, из чего следует, что, возможно, вы делаете что-то неправильно, так что давайте [mcve]

Код в студию!!!

Код добавила в вопрос, пишу на GDScript

А зачем вам запятые между строковыми представлениями символов, просто str(ibytes) не подходит? В общем, если вкратце, то конкатенация строк в некоторых версиях питона оптимизирована, но вообще она очень медленная, потому что строки иммутабельны. Тоже самое что вы делаете скорее всего можно сделать гораздо быстрее так без цикла и конкатенации строк посимвольно: ','.join(map(str, ibytes))

Мне кажется самый простой вариант просто хранить картинки на сервере,а в бд путь к ним

Сохраняйте в БД ibytes.

Более того — в документации godot-sqlite уже даже есть готовый пример сохранения текстуры в базу, а вы тут какую-то дичь творите зачем-то https://i.sstatic.net/F132f9Vo.png

Всем спасибо, получилось ускорить процесс

А можете, пожалуйста, скинуть ссылку, откуда сделан скрин? Интересно полностью почитать

Вот отсюда https://i.sstatic.net/iRBeQOj8.png

@BasicSloth, "бинарный" — это абсолютно всё, что не текст. И все форматы изображений являются частными случаями бинарного формата.

Не понимаю зачем в БД хранить картинку?! Хранить ссылку на картинку нельзя? Так она занимает меньше места, и приводит к меньшей фрагментации БД, в случае её замены. В комментариях вам хорошо всё расписали, любые данные бинарные, это цифровая среда. Везде сочетание единиц и нулей.

@AndreyMihalev Не, ну так то резоны могут быть. Например, если БД штатно бэкапится, а файловая система нет. Ну и вообще синхронизировать это всё между собой. А так единое место хранения. Но вообще конечно хранить бинарные данные в БД - не самое благодатное занятие, согласен.

@ГерманБорисов неправда, изображения XBM вполне текстовые

@ГерманБорисов а ещё кстати я вот тут недавно в комментах почти целую лекцию читал о том, почему «текстовый» и «бинарный» это на самом деле одно и то же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1590003
